# How to create a view for a model django

Tags: django, view

How do I build a function for this model to display team.name for members in my team on page and list my teams.members for members in my team ?

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='teams')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_teams', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, related_name='teams', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: You want to list all the team names along with their members or only a specific team. What's your use case here ?

Comment: You need to display the team name only for the team and the members of this team only for the team members themselves.I roughly know how to display the team name for members, but I don’t know how to display all members and their information, since mebers do not have a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Prakhar's answer (thnx so much:) ) I have compiled a more suitable solution for myself

views.py

```
def team_view(request):
    team = Team.objects.filter(members__in=[request.user]).first() // only shows to team members
    members = team.members.all()
    team_name = team.name
    context = {
        'team_name': team_name,
        "members":members
    }
    return render(request, 'team.html', context)
```

template.html

```
{{ team_name }}
{% for member in members %}
{{ member.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the great help to Prakhar:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are passing your team name as slug using url.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app_name.models import Team

def view_name(request, team_name):
    team = Team.objects.filter(name=team_name)[0]
    members = team.members.all()
    context = {"team_name":team_name, "members":members}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

In Template:

```
Team Name : {{team_name}}
{% for member in members %}
   {{member}}
{% endfor %}
```

Since your members field is M2M with User Model, you can access that using

```
{{ member.name }}
{{ member.email }}
.
.
. 
etc in your template
```

where `name, email` are fields of User Model

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer saved my day and helped me figure it out, I redid it a bit for what I wanted to publish now)

Comment: you can take a look at it below)

Answer (score 0):

#### views.py

```
def Teams(request):<br>
   team_list = Team.objects.all() 

   return render(request, template_name, {'team_list':team_list});
```

#### Team_Display.HTML

```
{% for  obj in team_list %}<br>
   <heading>{{obj.name}} </heading>
```